# Laravel - Setting Checked Property of Checkbox From Returned Array Input

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm having a problem where I'm trying to handle a

```
return Redirect::to('page')->withInput();
```

call while using an array of checkboxes. Basically, if my validator fails, I want to return back, display some errors and repopulate inputs with their value. Here are the inputs I'm having difficulty with.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="rms_cs[]" value="Marshall and Swift Property Valuation" {{ (Input::old("rms_cs[]") == "Marshall and Swift Property Valuation") ? "checked":"" }}> Marshall &amp; Swift Property Valuation
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="rms_cs[]" value="Premises Liability Survey" {{ (Input::old("rms_cs[]") == "Premises Liability Survey") ? "checked":"" }}> Premises Liability Survey
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, basically, I have multiple checkboxes, each with `name="rms_cs[]"` and `value="something"`. How would I go about setting the checked property to `checked` when Input is returned?

Note: I have lots of text boxes and radio buttons that work fine, so I know that the issue doesn't lie with anything besides `Input::old("rms_cs[]")`. I think the issue is that `rms_cs[]` is an indexed array; ie `rms_cs[0] = "Something"` and not `rms_cs["Premises Liability Survey"] = "Something"`

If anyone could shed some light on this/provide a better way to handle something like this, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I ended up figuring this out. I changed

```
name="rms_ssp[]"
```

on each checkbox to:

```
name="rms_ssp[epis]"
name="rms_ssp[mrp]"
```

etc, so the array was no longer indexed. Then, I made a variable out of the old input:

```
<?php $rms_ssp = Input::old('rms_ssp'); ?>
```

And added this check in each of the checkboxes:

```
{{ (isset($rms_ssp['epis'])) ? "checked":"" }}
{{ (isset($rms_ssp['mrp'])) ? "checked":"" }}
```

And that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Laravel Form&HTML builder to achieve what you want, plus doing some extra work in your controller.

In your controller, you manually construct a checkbox array as follows:

```
$boxes = array();
$checkboxInput = Input::get('box');
foreach ($checkboxInput as $box) {
    $boxes[$box] = true;
}
```

and then return with $boxes:

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('boxes',$boxes);
```

Next in your blade file, you use the Form class to set default checked value to either true or false like this:

```
{{Form::checkbox('box[]', 'box1', isset($boxes['box1']) && $boxes['box1'])}}
{{Form::checkbox('box[]', 'box2', isset($boxes['box2']) && $boxes['box2'])}}
```

And now you should see some checkboxes have been checked.

Comment: Good answer, but I opted out of using the `Form::checkbox` by preference. I did manage to find a solution, and I'll post the answer in a bit. But +1 for the good suggestions.

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks. But a little clunky. Yours is simpler.